# Texture changes in edit mode and object mode

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, scale

I made a simple rooftop model and i wanted to apply a texture to the walls, but when i unwrap and edit the uv and exit to the object mode the texture looks completely different. I feel like it has something to do with uniform scaling but it still occurs after setting the scale. Please help me out!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing the UV Map?

Comment: How does your shader setup (material node setup) look like?

Comment: maybe share your file with the packed image: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/